# Searching xml datagridview

Tags: xml, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

I'm trying to make it so that as user types in the search textbox it narrows down search result to a specific row. Also refresh button should show all rows. How do I make it search all columns and rows at the same time? datatype for each column is string. I intentionally made the primary key column hidden and using XML to keep it simple.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private xmlDatabaseData As String = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\xmlPriceData.xml"

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(xmlDatabaseData) = True Then
            ItemXMLData.ReadXml(xmlDatabaseData)

        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub txbSearch_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles txbSearch.TextChanged
        Me.ProductsBindingSource.ite = txbSearch.Text

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
        Me.Validate()
        ProductsBindingSource.EndEdit()
        ItemXMLData.WriteXml(xmlDatabaseData)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
        Me.Validate()
        ProductsBindingSource.EndEdit()
        ItemXMLData.WriteXml(xmlDatabaseData)
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
        ProductsBindingSource.AddNew()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnDelete_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
        Select Case MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete the selected item? ", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Confirm")
            Case MsgBoxResult.Yes
                Try
                    Me.ProductsBindingSource.RemoveCurrent()
                    Me.Validate()
                    Me.ProductsBindingSource.EndEdit()
                    ItemXMLData.WriteXml(xmlDatabaseData)
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MsgBox(ex.Message)
                End Try
            Case MsgBoxResult.No

            Case Else

        End Select
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnRefresh_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnRefresh.Click
        If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(xmlDatabaseData) = True Then
            ItemXMLData.ReadXml(xmlDatabaseData)

        End If
    End Sub 
End Class
```

Here is the gui

[image]

That's how it looks when i add some data and click save

[image]

and the table

[image]

Comment: The code you posted doesn't do anything to the XML. You read and write `ItemXMLData`, but you never change it. Where's the code that changes it?

Comment: Maybe you'd better show us how `ItemXMLData` is defined.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out about the title. When I debug it adds rows by clicking add button. I can write anything on the cells click save and it saves it. If I change it on specific cell and click save it does the job. I thought i didn't need to have additional code to change them. My goal was to make xml file as a datasource  so that I can just copy and paste a single xml file containing all the data if the program is to be installed in another machine. That way I don't have to re enter all the records. If this is not a good approach please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that you are not doing is doing something with your xml.  I used your base code and just modified it a bit.

Try this it will get you started and take your xml and stream it into an class objects.

1.) create your objects
ItemXMLData

ItemXMLDataProducts

If you have Visual Studio 2012 and your project open.  Copy your xml file and then go into a Class within your project and go to Edit then Paste Special and Paste XML as Class this will create your class objects.  ItemXMLData and ItemXMLDataProducts

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Xml.Serialization
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Xml
Public Class Form1


Private xmlDatabaseData As String = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory & "\xmlPriceData.xml"

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load


    If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(xmlDatabaseData) = True Then
        Dim xmlString As String

        xmlString = File.ReadAllText(xmlDatabaseData).Trim
        Dim obj As New ItemXMLData
        obj = ConvertFromXml(xmlString, GetType(ItemXMLData), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)


        DataGridView1.DataSource = obj.Products

    End If
End Sub


Public Shared Function ConvertFromXml(ByVal xml As String, ByVal objType As System.Type, ByVal encoding As System.Text.Encoding) As Object

    Dim o As Object = Nothing


    Dim serializer As XmlSerializer = New XmlSerializer(objType)
    Using ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(encoding.GetBytes(xml))
        Using xr As XmlTextReader = New XmlTextReader(ms)
            o = serializer.Deserialize(xr)
        End Using
    End Using



    Return o
End Function
End Class
```

These are your object Classes ItemXMLData & ItemXMLDataProducts

```
<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType:=True), _
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute([Namespace]:="", IsNullable:=False)> _
Partial Public Class ItemXMLData

Private productsField() As ItemXMLDataProducts

<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Products")> _
Public Property Products() As ItemXMLDataProducts()
    Get
        Return Me.productsField
    End Get
    Set(value As ItemXMLDataProducts())
        Me.productsField = Value
    End Set
End Property
End Class


<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType:=True)> _
Partial Public Class ItemXMLDataProducts

Private idField As Byte

Private barcodeField As String

Private nameField As String

Private priceField As Decimal


Public Property ID() As Byte
    Get
        Return Me.idField
    End Get
    Set(value As Byte)
        Me.idField = Value
    End Set
End Property


Public Property Barcode() As String
    Get
        Return Me.barcodeField
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        Me.barcodeField = Value
    End Set
End Property


Public Property Name() As String
    Get
        Return Me.nameField
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        Me.nameField = Value
    End Set
End Property


Public Property Price() As Decimal
    Get
        Return Me.priceField
    End Get
    Set(value As Decimal)
        Me.priceField = Value
    End Set
End Property
End Class
```